# Getting a total from seclected radio button

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and stuck with a problem. I'm trying to get a rolling total from selected radio and checkboxes. I've been trying for a week to get it right but i cant seem to figure it out.

```
<input type="radio" name="size" value="small">
<label>Small &euro;9.99 (perfect for a quick cup)</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="medium">Medium &euro;12.99 (normal days running)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="large">Large &euro;14.99 (for the 3 p.m slump)
<br>
<input type="radio" name="size" value="extra-Large">Extra-Large &euro;15.99 (for those stressful days)
<br>
</p>
Total
<input type="text" readonly id="total" />
<br/>
```

Above is a snippet of the html, i need the value to stay as `small, medium, large and extra-large` to be sent to the server.

I know what i want but i cant work out the syntax. Im looking for some help  thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried in terms of JavaScript to get this to work? Also.. you can only select 1 radio button which have the same `name`. So in your case, it can only be one of the values you mentioned, not all.

Comment: Currently your checkboxes themselves don't have any relationship with your specific values outside of the fact that they are next to them. You might want to consider adding a `data-*` attribute for each to indicate the value and then read that specific value when the element is checked (e.g. `<input type='radio' name='size' value='medium' data-price='12.99'>`)

Comment: Your example displays a number of issues. First, you have 3 elements with the same name (`"size"`). Second, you cannot do what you are describing without some JavaScript code. Do you have something besides what you are showing?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" class="radio" onclick="checkStatus" name="size" value="small">
<label>Small &euro;9.99 (perfect for a quick cup)</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="checkStatus" name="size" class="radio" value="medium">Medium &euro;12.99 (normal days running)
<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="checkStatus" class="radio" name="size" value="large">Large &euro;14.99 (for the 3 p.m slump)
<br>
<input type="radio" onclick="checkStatus" class="radio" name="size" value="extra-Large">Extra-Large &euro;15.99 (for those stressful days)
<br>
</p>
Total
<input type="text" readonly id="total" />
```

in javascript write:

```
function checkStatus(){
document.getElementsByClassName("radio").forEach(function(item){
      if(this.checked){
        alert(this.value);
      }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="small" price="9.99">
<label>Small &euro;9.99 (perfect for a quick cup)</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="medium" price="12.99">Medium &euro;12.99 (normal days running)
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="large" price="14.99">Large &euro;14.99 (for the 3 p.m slump)
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="size" value="extra-Large" price="15.99">Extra-Large &euro;15.99 (for those stressful days)
<br>
</p>
Total
<input type="text" readonly id="total" />
<br/>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").click(function(e){
    var baseVal = parseFloat($("#total").val()) || 0;
    if($(e.target).find(":checked").context.checked)
    $("#total").val(baseVal+parseFloat($(e.target).attr("price")));
    else
    $("#total").val(baseVal-parseFloat($(e.target).attr("price")));
    });

});
```

fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/1j81w1q5/5/

Answer (score 0):

> Work on your HTML it's not up to standard

```
 <input type="radio" name="size" value="small" onclick="setYourTotal('Small&euro;9.99 ')" />Small &euro;9.99 (perfect for a quick cup)
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="medium" onclick="setYourTotal('Medium &euro;12.99')" />Medium &euro;12.99 (normal days running)
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="large" onclick="setYourTotal('Large &euro;14.99')" />Large &euro;14.99 (for the 3 p.m slump)
      <br>
      <input type="radio" name="size" value="extra-Large" onclick="setYourTotal('Extra-Large &euro;15.99')" />Extra-Large &euro;15.99 (for     those stressful days)
      <br>Total
      <input type="text" readonly id="total" />
```

> Easy JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    function setYourTotal(data) {
        document.getElementById("total").value = data;
    }

</script>
```